# Вводное сочетание в неполном виде

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вводные-слова

**Коррективы были внесены так, чтобы, с одной стороны, строительство шло быстрее, но, с другой, чтобы это не поставило застройщика в тупик.**

**Коррективы были внесены так, чтобы, с одной стороны, строительство шло быстрее, но с другой — чтобы это не поставило застройщика в тупик.**

Есть правило, что "если вводное сочетание образует неполную конструкцию (пропущено какое-либо слово, восстанавливаемое из контекста), то оно выделяется запятой и тире: *Макаренко неоднократно подчёркивал, что педагогика основана, с одной стороны, на безграничном доверии к человеку, а с другой — на высоких к нему требованиях*" (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122).

Однако у нас союз "но" и неполное вводное сочетание "с другой" не образуют единое сочетание, сочетание "с другой" можно изъять или переставить в другое место.

Предложение без вводных:

**Коррективы были внесены так, чтобы строительство шло быстрее, но чтобы это не поставило застройщика в тупик.**

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, корректно так:

**Коррективы были внесены так, чтобы, с одной стороны, строительство шло быстрее, но с другой — чтобы это не поставило застройщика в тупик.**

Вы не можете отбросить "с другой" и оставить "с одной", а раз уж у вас есть такая конструкция "с одной стороны... с другой", то действует правило про запятую и тире, и не так важно, стоит там союз *а* или союз *но* или союзов нет совсем.

Answer (score 0):

**Примеры** сходных конструкций (постановка тире здесь зависит от паузы):

Всё это было, с одной стороны, понятно, *но с другой* ― всё-таки как-то ненормально. [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)] 
С одной стороны, я понимал, что он меня просто не заметил, *но с другой*, мне всё мерещилось, что он от меня сбежал. [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

Надо сказать, что вариант "но с другой" часто применяется в текстах, при этом "но" может быть соединительным или присоединительным союзом, запятая ставится или не ставится.

**А как правильно?** Рекомендации Розенталя на эту тему не рассматривают конкретно именно тот случай, когда вводное слово неполное, а союз НО сочинительный (соединительный), так что решать задачу придется самим  и желательно с учетом того, как это делают другие. (Не всё же у Розенталя списывать).

Союз "но" может соединяться с вводным словом? Присоединительный союз может (по Розенталю), но и соединительный (в сложном предложении) тоже неплохо смотрится.

Тире ставится зачем?  Оно обозначает паузу на месте пропуска слова: нет паузы — нет тире. И чтобы поставить тире, нужно слитное произношение "но с другой", так что запятая здесь будет не у места.

Поэтому выбираем **следующее решение**: *Коррективы были внесены так, чтобы, с одной стороны, строительство шло быстрее, но с другой — чтобы это не поставило застройщика в тупик.*

А вот как это делают другие пользователи (запятую и тире вроде бы никто не ставит).

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%EE%20%F1%20%E4%F0%F3%E3%EE%E9&p=1